# How to drop root privileges from a POSIX shell script?

Tags: shell, root

What portable options do exist to drop root privileges and execute a given command as a different user from a shell script?

After doing a bit of research, here are a few non-options:

- `su $USER -c "$COMMAND"` uses the PAM stack and creates a new cgroup (when run under systemd). It also fails in user namespaces, because the audit call returns -EPERM on older versions of Linux.
- `sudo -u $USER $COMMAND` is not installed by default on many systems.
- `start-stop-daemon --pidfile /dev/null --start --chuid $USER --startas /bin/sh -- -c "$COMMAND"` is very hard to use and only available on Debian systems.
- `chpst -u $USER $COMMAND` is missing on many systems.
- `runuser -u $USER -- $COMMAND` works where `su` doesn't, but requires recent util-linux.

Comment: Regarding the first part of point 1, is this another systemd f-up? I like to hear about those.

Comment: @Kaz Relevant thread starts at https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2014/05/msg00371.html

Answer (score 3):

If it's POSIX you want, then `su` is your only option (unless you want to write a C program). `su` has several advantages (or not, depending on your requirements):

- It's a system tool which isn't going to forget about the new coffee UID introduced in Linux 3.42 (the UID for beverage drinking purposes) and which isn't going to goof by dropping user privileges before group privileges or to forget about capabilities.
- It sets privileges to a known state: a user ID, that user's recorded group(s) from the user and group databases, no extra capabilities.
- It records log entries.
- And, again, it's completely standard, guaranteed to be available everywhere but on the most broken systems.

Now in practice some systems aren't POSIX — like this older Linux where it fails in user namespaces. Them's the breaks.

If you want something that's reasonably portable in practice (on non-embedded platforms) and that gives you a greater decree of control, use Perl (or Python, a bit less commonly installed). For preference, use a solid module: [Privilege::Drop](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Privileges%3A%3ADrop).

```
perl -e 'use Privileges::Drop; drop_uid_gid(123, 456); exec("/path/to/command", "--option", "an argument")'
```

`Privilege::Drop` takes care of doing things right (dropping supplemental groups, checking for errors). It might not be complete, however; for example it isn't aware of capabilities.

If you must do it by hand, take care of several things:

- Drop group privileges before user privileges.
- To drop supplemental groups, set `$) = "456 456"` where 456 is the target GID (`$) = 456` would only set the EGID without affecting the supplemental groups).
- Check the (E)[UG]ID afterwards and abort on failure.

Comment: If su is the way to go, what does it take to make su work again? Upgrading the kernel is the easy part, but the systemd part still bites.

Comment: @HelmutGrohne I don't know. I suggest asking on [unix.se] where there are a few systemd afficionados (I'm not).

Answer (score 3):

For folks who are reading this in a context where the relevant meaning of "POSIX shell script" is "POSIX sh script, being run on an arbitrary Linux system", as opposed to "sh script, run on a system guaranteed to have only tools guaranteed by POSIX", there are more options available.

Borrowing from an excellent answer to the [UNIX & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) question [How do I drop root privileges in shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132663/how-do-i-drop-root-privileges-in-shell-scripts):

- Modern `util-linux` has `setpriv`, which can be used in the manner of:

  ```
  setpriv --reuid=user --regid=group --init-groups --inh-caps=-all yourcommand
  ```

The excellent article by [@JdeBP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/5132/jdebp) [Don't Abuse `su` For Dropping Privileges](http://jdebp.info/FGA/dont-abuse-su-for-dropping-privileges.html) is also worth reading.

Comment: I have seen the linked article first, and it led me to this Q&A... because it seems to me like `setuidgid` is not actually a better tool for the job: It does not update the environment variables. e.g. `$HOME` will still be `/root` ... I am not convinced why it would be better than `su`. The `setpriv` tool you are recommending seems to have the `--reset-env` option, so thank you for the recommendation!

Comment: But using `su` still seems a lot easier than getting all those flags right?

Comment: @lucidbrot If you only care about "easy", and not about "secure", I suggest that system administration (or development in contexts where one maintains code that crosses privilege boundaries) is not a good career choice. _Which_ linked article have you previously read? I'd call the JdeBP one pretty convincing.

Comment: `su -c '...'`, in starting a shell, adds complexity (thus, room for bugs) that isn't there when you have a direct chain of `execv`'d argument lists; it makes it harder to safely parameterize the code being invoked than it should be, as one needs to know how to escape the command for the target shell. But bigger-picture, and more concerning, going up-then-down drops any prior containment work that may have been done to have a process running as a restricted form of root, vs root uncontained. Remember, there are capabilities, security contexts, &c in play today, not just the legacy model

Comment: ...and shell startup itself introduces new potential attack surface; if processes running as an unprivileged user are only ever invoked in a way that doesn't involve an interactive or login shell, then attacks involving dotfiles &c are off the table. Don't involve a shell at all and `ENV` / `BASH_ENV` &c are also off the table.

Comment: Well, I meant "easy" as in "easy to get it right". E.g. dropping privileges without specifying `--reset-env` and then performing some automated git pulls results in git trying to look in `/root` for a config. With `su` that just works correctly on its own. To make sure I get the point right: Is there anything in itself wrong/insecure about `su` if all I want to do is go from fully-capable root to some unprivileged user? Or is it only introducing larger attack surface due to complexity?

Comment: It's _less_ wrong if you're starting from fully-capable root for sure, but it still forces you to start a shell and engages all the configurable moving pieces involved in PAM. Starting a shell isn't necessarily _insecure_, but it's certainly _extra attack surface_, so better to avoid when it's easy to do so; doubly so if one's parameterizing the command being invoked. Similarly, correctly-configured PAM rules enhance security, but it's still an increase in the number of things happening behind your back. Using a tool that's verbose about what it does keeps the moving parts in view. :)